# How to get Flask to print my list data as is without html formating?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

My data looks like this from flask server side

```
data = [
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
    ]
    return render_template("candle.html",title = 'Candle',data=data)
```

On my webpage it looks like the below:

```
{% for row  in data %}
            {{row}},
         {% endfor %}

        [&#39;Mon&#39;, 20, 28, 38, 45],

        [&#39;Tue&#39;, 31, 38, 55, 66],

        [&#39;Wed&#39;, 50, 55, 77, 80],

        [&#39;Thu&#39;, 77, 77, 66, 50],

        [&#39;Fri&#39;, 68, 66, 22, 15],
```

How do I get the data e.g. the first liem to look this this?

```
&#39;Mon&#39; ===> Mon
```

I am passing data for a google api chart

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
{% for row  in data %}
    {{ row[0] }},
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wat does not not print my data lit I need it

Comment: @Tampa: are you trying to use the values in Javascript perhaps? Then *don't loop* and use `{{ data|tojson }}` instead, which produces a HTML-safe JavaScript subset.